# React Native Text Input changes height after typing on android

Tags: javascript, react-native, textview, textinput

I have to create a typing bar for a chat in React Native, but I have a problem on Android.

The red component is a `TextInput` that have `multiline enabled` and `maxHeight: 100`.

The `problem` is the height of it after one line. You can see in the first photo that after I press `enter` the height has changed.

[image]

After I start to type something, the height has changed again:

[image]

This problems occurs only on `android`, but in iOS the height of `TextInput` is the same either the line is empty or does have something written on.

If `TextInput` have a `predefined height and multiline enabled` it doesn't have this problem, only if I add a `minHeight` and `maxHeight`.

Can somebody help me figure this out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hard code the height so that it knows what height to take first, then specify the maxHeight both of them should be inside the styles, if you still have the same issue try to use debugging to inspect the input and see if the height and maxHeight r there so to be sure it had taken it into consideration..
You can also wrap the input with a View and fix the height of it.

Update since you modified it rn———————————

I would suggest that you make height fixed on the onChange event so it can work properly

Comment: it also takes a `minHeight` to have a start height. also tried to get rid of the text input text padding, but still no effect

Comment: it's best if you can inspect the TextInput and see what styles it has